# Differences between builtin and user defined methods in Python3

Tags: methods, python-3.x, member

I noticed that member functions of built-in and user-defined classes have different types. Does that mean the two may behave differently in some situations?

```
class A:
  def a():
    pass

>>> type(A.a), type(list.append)
(<class 'function'>, <class 'method_descriptor'>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both perform their function normally, if that's what you mean. They both are callable. Otherwise there are few differences between them.

One difference is that you can set arbitrary attributes on `function` objects, but not on a C function (such as `list.append)`.

Another is that a Python function has a code object associated with it, containing the compiled bytecode and information about local variables and such. The C function, naturally, lacks that information.

Comment: Well, I am much more knowledgeable in C++ than in Python. In C++ different types imply different interfaces, while related types imply interchangeability. However, in Python, unrelated types can often be interchanged as well, which at times makes me clueless about what is safe and what is not. Thanks for your answer!